# Confuse Viewport Config

Tags: css, viewport

I'm trying create a simple CSS responsive layout and in my computer everything seems very fine. But when I access by my phone (Nokia 710) the elements get bigger than normal.

Here's what I have:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

html, body, ul, li { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body, input, select { font-family: Arial; font-size: 0.800em; }
li { float: left; display: inline; margin: 1px; background-color: #d9d9d9; text-align: center; overflow: hidden; }

li { width: 5vw; height: 5vw; background-color: #aaa; }

@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
  li { width: 0.5vw; height: 0.5vw; background-color: red; }
}
```

With this code, in my phone the layout works fine. But debugging on Chrome Device the elements are too small.

This should be a simple layout and don't get it what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my codepen: http://codepen.io/rochapablo/full/EaJxZP/

And the browser:
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows Phone OS 7.5; Trident/5.0; IEMobile/9.0; NOKIA; Lumia 710)

UPDATE

I don't get it why using vw the width of the devices are different. So i've tried % and worked. I'm not 100% satisfied but this have worked in all devices with same the same code.

```
li { width: calc(100% / 4 - 2px); height: 50px; line-height: 50px; }
li:nth-child(1) { width: calc(100% / 4 - 2px); height: 102px; line-height: normal; text-align: left; }
li:nth-child(4) { width: calc(100% / 4 - 2px); height: 50px; }
li:nth-child(5) { width: calc(100% / 2 - 2px); height: 50px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your width and height values are using the viewport width (vw) and height (vh) values with no minimums set.

This will cause your elements to become infinitely small in relation to the viewport size.

I would recommend adding in min-width and min-height values for your li elements.

e.g.

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
  li { 
    width: 0.5vw; 
    height: 0.5vw; 
    min-width:200px; /** ADDED **/
    min-height:200px; /** ADDED **/ 
    background-color: red; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Right! Looking at this point. But why on the simulation and on the mobile device are not equal? Since both are the same size?

Comment: To confirm do you realize that your desktop view has the li element set at 5vw while your mobile is only at .5vw?  That's quite a large difference and will make the mobile version much smaller.

Comment: Yes, I realize. By the way, it should work both media on 5vw, right?

Comment: Please keep backwards compatibility in mind re vw — just over 10% of site traffic in the US, and 17% globally, do not support this unit. http://caniuse.com/#search=vw